# How to access local server which has custom url from Android Emulator

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator

I am working on a Cordova application. The front-end of the app is based on React. It is running in my local development machine (Mac) has has a custom link `m.local.sese.com`. This front-end depends on more local services like chat-bot, mysql, etc. All these services are built with Docker and running on my local machine as well. I am able to access the link `m.local.sese.com` from my Android Emulator but I get connection refused when I try to access from my Cordova app.

Now I have found many links on Stackoverflow which asked the same questions and I tried almost all the answers but nothing worked for me.

Most of the answers deal with ip and port number (127.0.0.1:3000) etc. But in my case I do not know the ip and port number of my custom url. How do i access this custom url from my Android emulator?

Comment: Connection refused seems like a CORS issue

Comment: How do I fix that? any suggestion? @DGK

Comment: Your back-end at m.local.sese.com needs to accept the origin you're sending. Check your network request and maybe logging to get some more info beyond 'connection refused'

Comment: Seems like a CORS issue, but not clear if it actually is. For Cors I have a [guide](https://breautek.com/articles/enabling-cors.html) (tailored to WKWebView but the exact same concept applies to android as well)